# Render child components with Enzymejs tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test a simple component that take some props (it have no state, or redux connection) with `Enzyme`, it works for the plain elements like `<div />` and so on, but when i try to test if the element rendered by the child component exists, it fails.

I'm trying to use mount but it spit me a lot of errors, i'm new in this so, here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import WordCloud from 'react-d3-cloud';

class PredictWordCloud extends Component {
  render() {
    const fontSizeMapper = word => Math.log2(word.value) * 3.3;
    const { size, data, show } = this.props;

    if (!show)
      return <h3 className='text-muted text-center'>No data</h3>

    return (
      <section id='predict-word-cloud'>
        <div className='text-center'>
          <WordCloud
            data={data}
            fontSizeMapper={fontSizeMapper}
            width={size}
            height={300} />
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default PredictWordCloud;
```

It's just a wrapper for `<WordCloud />`, and it just recieves 3 props directly from his parent: `<PredictWordCloud data={wordcloud} size={cloudSize} show={wordcloud ? true : false} />`, anything else.

The tests is very very simple for now:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import PredictWordCloud from '../../components/PredictWordCloud.component';
import cloudData from '../../helpers/cloudData.json';

describe('<PredictWordCloud />', () => {
  let wrapper;

  beforeEach(() => {
     wrapper = shallow(<PredictWordCloud data={cloudData} size={600} show={true} />)
  });

  it('Render without problems', () => {
     const selector = wrapper.find('#predict-word-cloud');
     expect(selector.exists()).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

**For now it pass** but if we change the selector to: `const selector = wrapper.find('#predict-word-cloud svg');` where the `svg` tag is the return of `<Wordcloud />` component, the tests fails because the assertion returns `false`.

**I tried to use mount instead of shallow**, exactly the same test, but i get a big error fomr `react-d3-cloud`:

> PredictWordCloud Render without problems TypeError: Cannot read property 'getImageData' of null.

This is specially weird because it just happens in the test environment, the UI and all behaviors works perfectly in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can find your component directly by Component name.
Then you can use find inside your sub-component as well.

e.g

```
  it('Render without problems', () => {
     const selector = wrapper.find('WordCloud').first();
     expect(selector.find('svg')).to.have.length(1);

  });
```

or 
 You can compare generated html structure as well via

```
  it('Render without problems', () => {
     const selector = wrapper.find('WordCloud').first();
     expect(selector.html()).to.equal('<svg> Just an example </svg>');

  });
```